# Identifying the used base class in a type-parameterized Test using googletest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

A physics simulation is being refurbished and I am trying to write unittests for functions which are to be replaced using type-parameterized tests. The basic setup looks something like this:

```
using MyTypes = ::testing::Types<base1<1>, base1<2>, base2<1>, base2<2>>;
TYPED_TEST_CASE(tests, MyTypes);
TYPED_TEST(tests, testname){
  auto obj = clname(TypeParam);
  auto parameters = generate_values(TypeParam);      
  for( auto& p : parameters ){
    // Test if obj.func(p) equals the saved values
  }
}
```

Since the number of base classes and generated values is large, I'd like to write the outputs of the current (presumed correct) version to a file and compare the outputs of new versions to these values. The function (func) changes depending on TypeParam, so I need to save the used base class in some form as well.

However, I don't know how to identify the base class used: One solution would be to save and compare the typeid, as in saving

```
typeid(TypeParam).name()
```

along with the results, but I've been told that this is value can change between machines and is therefore not useful as a value to use. I've tried to find the corrosponding entry in MyTypes, i.e. saving i for which

```
std::is_same<MyTypes[i],TypeParam>::value
```

is true, but this seems not to be the case for any i. Is there any good way to do this with a type-parameterized test? Or do I need to use something else entirely?

Comment: Maybe [std::is_base_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) could be of use..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can label `base1<1>`, `base1<2>`, `base2<1>`, `base2<2>`, ... by one dimensional integers `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, ... using the following class template `TestsWrapper`.
More specifically, `TestsWrapper<...T>::getIdx<U>()` returns the position of the type `U` in the [**parameter pack**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) `...T`.
For instance,

- `TestsWrapper<A,B,C,D,E>::getIdx<A>()` is `0`,
- `TestsWrapper<A,B,C,D,E>::getIdx<B>()` is `1`,
- `TestsWrapper<A,B,C,D,E>::getIdx<C>()` is `2`,

and so on.
This enables us to identify the tested class as `TestsWrapper<base1<1>, base1<2>, base2<1>, base2<2>>::getIdx<TypeParam>()` at compile-time:

[**Live DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DEIY1fH7QaedW8jD)

```
template<class ...T>
class TestsWrapper
{
   template<class U>
   static constexpr std::size_t getIdx_impl()
   {
       return 0;
   }

   template<class U, class T0, class ...Ts>
   static constexpr std::size_t getIdx_impl()
   {
       return std::is_same<U, T0>::value ? 0 : (getIdx_impl<U, Ts...>() + 1);
   }

public:
   using Types = ::testing::Types<T...>;

   template<class U>
   static constexpr std::size_t getIdx()
   {
       return getIdx_impl<U, T...>();
   }
};
```

The usage example of this class template for the typed tests is as follows.
Here `idx` is the above integer label `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, ... and saves which type is currently tested.
You can use this label to identify the currently tested class.
I have already checked that this approach well works in my Windows environment:

```
using TWrapper = TestsWrapper<base1<1>, base1<2>, base2<1>, base2<2>>;

template <typename T>
class test : public ::testing::Test {};

TYPED_TEST_CASE(test, TWrapper::Types);

TYPED_TEST(test, testname)
{
   constexpr auto idx = TWrapper::getIdx<TypeParam>();
   ...
}
```